# Using .delegate or .live with if statements (if empty do blah blah blah) on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-delegate

2 fold issue.

I need to hide an element(A) if another element(B) is empty and show A if B has elements within.

And I need to do this on elements loaded dynamically.

So I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#mapDirections').html().trim()) {
    $('#mapReset').hide();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#mapReset').show();
  }
});
```

But that didn't work, and I didn't think it would - I've used delegate and live on click events, but not sure how to use them in conjunction with what I want to do.

Comment: That won't work with dynamic HTML because the elements you're looking for don't exist for the selectors to find when you are applying this function.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni - ok, the element #mapDirections exists - but is empty. As elements are appended to it, I want other elements to show and if it's empty, I want to hide elements

Comment: Is your code responsible for adding to it?  If so, why not add the appropriate code at that point?

Comment: per @JeffB, move your show/hide code to where you are appending error messages.  Or wrap it in a function and call the function after you append to #mapDirections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you have control of the JavaScript that is populating #mapDirections. you should implement the callback behavior then, immediately after the data arrives.

If you don't have that control and the new data is stochastic then you'll need to determine a time interval to poll the node for new content.

For instance, suppose onNewMapDirections() is called in response to some event in the DOM:

```
function onNewMapDirections(newData) {
  $('#mapDirections').html(newData);
  //Add callback here
}
```

This could be done easily by binding and triggering custom event handlers on the document:

```
//Called when new directions are ready to add to DOM
function onNewMapDirections(newData) {
  $('#mapDirections').html(newData);
  $(document).trigger('checkMapDirections');
}

//Called in response to dispatched event
function onMapDirectionsUpdated(evt) {
  if ($('#mapDirections').html().trim()) $('#mapReset').hide();
  else  $('#mapReset').show();
}

//Binds event
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind('checkMapDirections', onMapDirectionsUpdated);
});
```

If you aren't able to embed the callback as soon as new map data calls in, you can still use the event logic and implement a timer that periodically calls

```
$(document).trigger('checkMapDirections');
```